# How do I include jvmstat?

Tags: java, build, jvm

I am compiling a JDK6 project and is having build errors about not being able to find `sun.jvmstat.monitor.MonitoredHost` (and other classes under that package). My question is what library should I include to satisfy this import: `import sun.jvmstat.monitor.*;`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [jarfinder.com](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/sun.jvmstat.monitor.MonitoredHost):

- `tools.jar`.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response and the useful site!